# Can't click on nav-bar, body when modal is open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Currently I'm using modal like a popup at bottom of webpage.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="slide-bottom-popup"  data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button id="close" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4>Cennos Commandments</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Commandments 1</li>
            <li>Commandments 2</li>
            <li>Commandments 3</li>
            <li>Commandments 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS for modal

```
.modal.fade.in .modal-body {
    bottom: 0; 
    opacity: 1;
}
.modal-body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -250px;
    right: 0%;
    padding: 30px 15px 15px;
    width: 275px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, bottom 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, bottom 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, bottom 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, bottom 0.3s ease-out;
}
.close {
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
body.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Script to make it open on page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#slide-bottom-popup').modal('show');
}, 0); // milliseconds
});
```

I realize that I have to close the modal first before I can click or select on body or nav-bar to go to other pages. Is there anyway that I can keep the modal open and still can use body,nav-bar at the same time.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/02u302v4/ .
Overwrite modal class :

```
.modal {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it only works for the right side of the modal. If the modal pop-up at center, I can only click on the right side of modal, the left side still disabled.

Comment: @SaoHo : Please check the updated answer. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Here it is working. I can interact with the background, even when the modal box is open.

Comment: well ur question was, u want to click on the navbar. well now in the answer u can click on the navbar.

Comment: Sorry about that :) I accepted your answer. Thank you